# How to get timezone from postal code using Java?

Tags: datetime, timezone, utc

I have some Java code and I need to implement logic that finds  timezone from postal code of UK region. Do we have any service that does the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland uses Europe/London time zone. Including Northern Ireland, Man, Jersey and Guernsey. So you just need `ZoneId.of("Europe/London")` always.

**Link:** [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)